# How do I check if my clangd compilation database is valid?

Tags: c++, clang

I generate a compilation database in a project built by `autotools` using [compiledb](https://github.com/nickdiego/compiledb) in WSL environment.
Then I copy resultant `compile_commands.json` to another directory and run `clangd` in Windows environment.
I convert all the Unix paths to their Windows equivalents. And now I want to check if I converted it correctly and `clangd` finds all the files in the json.

When I use CLion as a front-end I can't see if the processing of some entries failed.

Does clang toolchain have some utilities for validation `compile_commands.json`?

Answer (score 1):

You can run `clangd` with following options:

```
clangd --compile-commands-dir path/to/directory/containing/compile_commands.json --check=path/to/file.cpp
```

If the `compile_commands.json` is valid, it prints following output:

```
I[11:16:53.056] Loading compilation database...
I[11:16:53.056] Loaded compilation database from /full/path/to/directory/containing/compile_commands.json
```

If it is invalid, it prints following output (in this example I changed `directory` to `directoryuuuuu` in the `compile_commands.json` file):

```
I[11:14:26.396] Loading compilation database...
E[11:14:26.396] Failed to load compilation database from /full/path/to/directory/containing/compile_commands.json: Unknown key: ""directoryuuuuu""
I[11:14:26.396] Failed to find compilation database for /full/path/to/file.cpp
```